# Bayesian inference with geometric distribution, verify $p(y > r|\theta) = (1-\theta)^r \text{ , where } r = 1,2,...$

Tags: statistical-inference, bayesian

The geometric distribution is given by: $$p(y|\theta) = (1-\theta)^{y-1}\theta \text{ , where } y=1,2,..., 0 < \theta < 1$$ Verify that: $$p(y > r|\theta) = (1-\theta)^r \text{ , where } r = 1,2,...$$

How does one actually go about doing this? I tried a few integrals with different limits across $ (1-\theta)^{y-1}\theta$ but that did not make too much progress. I can't find any similar examples in course literature. Any hints to get started appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Simplify\begin{align}
P(Y>r|\theta) &= \sum_{y=r+1}^\infty (1-\theta)^{y-1} \theta
\end{align}

perhaps using geometric series.

Comment: Great, thanks. Although where does the summation come from? Is that a commonly accepted result? Or to do with the likelihood.

Comment: we are dealing with discrete probability, so summation rather than integral. $P(Y>r|theta) = P(Y=r+1|\theta)+ P(Y=r+2|\theta)+\ldots $.